# QML TypeError when move customized control into its own file

Tags: qt, qml, controls

I have successfully styled a QML Switch as per documentation, and it works well.  I now want to reuse my styled switch, but when I move the switch code into its own file I get these errors:

```
qml/QtQuick/Controls/Switch.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'max' of null
qml/QtQuick/Controls/Switch.qml:123: TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of null
qml/QtQuick/Controls/Switch.qml:122: TypeError: Cannot read property '__handle' of null
MySwitch.qml:28: TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchStyle' of undefined
```

The MySwitch code is as follow:

```
import Felgo 3.0
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12 as Q

Q.Switch {
    id: switchControl
    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 48 +textOff.width - 5
        implicitHeight: 26
        x: parent.leftPadding  //sc
        y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 13
        color: parent.checked ? "black" : "white"  //sc
        border.color: "black"
        // Control center circle
        Rectangle {
            x: parent.parent.checked ? parent.width - width : 0
            width: 26
            height: 26
            radius: 13
            color: "white"
            border.color: "black"
        }  // <-- This is line 28

        // On text
        MultiResolutionImage {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            x: 13 -5
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "../../assets/img/scenesettings/texton.png"
            visible: parent.checked  //sc
        }

        // Off text
        MultiResolutionImage {
            id: textOff
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            x: parent.width - textOff.width - 13 + 5 // Outside of radius
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "../../assets/img/scenesettings/textoff.png"
            visible: !parent.checked  // switchControl
        }
    }  // Indicator    
}  // Switch
```

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: show the imports

Comment: Question update to show imports.  The "felgo" was is necessary for the "MultiResolutiomnImage" - I don't think that's a factor

Comment: Is this code the complete file? The error says line 28 of MySwitch.qml, but `switchStyle` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you are showing.

Comment: I've removed non-essential lines to simplify the example.  I noted line 28 in the comment above

Comment: You're getting errors from "qml/QtQuick/Controls/Switch.qml". That's QuickControls 1. But your code shows you importing QuickControls 2. None of this makes any sense.

Comment: It turns out Felgo implements its own Switch.qml, using QuickControls 1.x.  So I tried to force switch to use QuickControls 2.12 (import as Q) and use Q.Switch but the error still reference's Felgo's implementation.  How can I force it to NOT use felgo's implementation?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent name collisions, you can add a prefix name for imports using the `as` keyword, like this:

```
import Felgo 3.0 as MyLibrary
```

Then in order to use anything from that module, you will need to use that name:

```
MyLibrary.MultiResolutionImage {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that (see my post from 14 hr ago) - but use of Q.Switch still uses the Felgo version.  Not sure why

Comment: I missed that edit to your post. But then your errors make no sense. It's not possible for Q.Switch to refer to Felgo.

Comment: I don't understand it either.  Starting to wonder if Felgo IDE has removed/replaced Qt libraries with their own.  Can't figure it out.